# mailto tag is being prepended by site name\page name\

Tags: php, mailto, prepend

I'm developing a footer for a Wordpress site (not live yet, using Local by Flywheeel for now). I'm having trouble with the mailto tag. When hovered over or clicked, the link prepends sitename/pagename/ to the email address. How can I fix this?

See the HTML embedded into functions.php, below:

```
function avada_render_footer_copyright_notice() {
  ?>
  <p class="custom-credits">© 2019
  <?php echo (date('Y') > 2019)? '- '.date('Y') : '';?>
  <a target="_blank"
  href="http://www.example.com">Made with <span>&#10084;</span> &nbsp;by Me | &phone;&nbsp;(555) 555-5555<a>
  <a href="client@example.com">&#x2709;&nbsp;Email Us</a>
          </p>
  <?php
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your href attribute needs to be `"mailto:client@example.com"`.  If your href does not have the mailto prefix, the browser assumes it is a site-relative hyperlink.